# HOW to Parse JSON response from the server after AJAX POST-request?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, parsing

As you can see the problem from the title.
Here is what I do:

send a request like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://www.example.com/api/",
  data: {
    'data': '1',
    'beacon': 'fried'
  },
  complete: function(res) {
    //need help here...
  }
});
```

The API does echo. 
If I do `document.forms["myform"].submit();`
page shows a JSON response like

```
{
  "data": [{
    "Chief": "Max",
    "temperature": "65",
    "done": "yes",
    "cost": 24
  }]
}
```

So how should I parse (check, display the values)? Tried many ways.

Any help would be appreciated !

P.S. using jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first problem was that it does not allow to response come out from different domain, so I transferred all the code to the same server where api is located.

Now this code works:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../api/",
  data: {'data': '1', 'beacon': 'fried'},
  dataType: 'JSON',
  complete: function (res) {
  console.log(res);
  var r = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
  console.log(r.data[0].Chief); //retrieved Alex, that is response from the server
  }
});
```

Thanks all !

Comment: Great but you don't need to parse it again. It's decoded yet.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the dataType to JSON in the request attribute :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/api/",
    data: {'data': '1', 'beacon': 'fried'},
    dataType: 'JSON',
    complete: function (res) {
        console.log(res); // will be decoded
        // acces your values like this :
        var data = res.responceText.data[0];
        alert(data.Chief);
    }
 });
```

**EDIT**

Added how to access specific data.

Comment: much simpler than all the other answers and also handles error internally for invalid json

Comment: but this will only work if we sure that response is JSON.

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar all the more reason to use it...will go to error callback (and reject promise)  if there is a parse error

Comment: @JazZ we must say this is the very simple and error handler answer

Comment: @JazZ Yes, that is really the most adaptable and convenient way. So I can see the response in 'responseText' in console. But how do I get that particular values ? Thanks for help you all !

Comment: @khuma glad it helped. You can access it with something like `res.data['Chief']`.

Comment: I`m getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Chief' of undefined" if I do res.data['Chief'] I`m really getting dumb with this...

Comment: @khuma Sorry, it's almost that. Try it with something like `res.data[0].Chief`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @JazZ No that didn`t work same error. I tried `console.log(JSON.parse(res.responseText))` and got
`"[arrow button] Object {data: Array(1)}"`
If I click on arrow button "[arrow button] data:Array(1)" I go deeper occurs "[arrow button] 0:Object" once more and I can see all the variables
So hierarchy is like:

Comment: @khuma could you please add the output of `console.log(res)` to your question ? that way, we will know how you can access the values.

Comment: @JazZ Works ! But First I initialized variable json = JSON.parse(res.responseText); console.log(json.data[0].Chief);

Comment: @khuma Ok glad it works but it's already decoded. No need to parse this again right ?

Comment: So, I think you could do : `res.responceText.data[0].Chief` directly, isn't it ? We just missed the `responceText` level because it is not show in your question.

Comment: @Khuma you can access this ` res.data[0].Chief ` like that where is `responceText` in your json.

Answer (score 2):

you should use

> JSON.parse()

As you have array in in json data , you can access it as res.data[0].cost or  res.data[0]["cost"]

Comment: Thanks, I needed JSON.parse(res.responseText); that`s what I didn`t know

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped, please mark it as correct answer, if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse()` if needed otherwise you can get array from `res.data`

Comment: @Khuma `data` is an array of objects. Try `alert(res.data[0]["cost"]) `

Answer (score 1):

Try `JSON.parse()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/api/",
    data: {'data': '1', 'beacon': 'fried'},
    complete: function (res) {
       var arr = JSON.parse(res).data;

       arr.forEach(function(obj) {
           var cost = obj.cost || null,
                Chief = obj.Chief || null,
                temperature = obj.temperature || null,
                done = obj.done || null;

           console.log('Cost: ' + cost + ', Chief: ' + Chief + ', Temperature:' + temperature + ', Done: ' + done);
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: why? Do this with dataType so it gets parsed internally and will go to error callback if not valid json

Comment: agree @charlietfl, but anyway I tried this way too @MH2K9 I`ve got an error

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSON.parse()`

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.example.com/api/",
        data: {'data': '1', 'beacon': 'fried'},
        complete: function (res) {
          var response = JSON.parse(res); 
        }
     });
```